# Magento $category->getURL() issue for adding rel="alternate"

Tags: magento

Attempting to work out a solution to incorporate rel="alternate" tags into a multi-language Mage store. Note: categories and products have customised URL keys for each store

The below code works properly and gives me the correct full URL for a product, in the format of http://www.storename.com/storecode/product.phtml

```
$url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product->getId())->getProductUrl();
```

But the below does not work for categories.  It gives the same store code for each URL, instead of the correct store code for each store in the foreach:

```
$url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($category->getId())->getUrl();
```

In head.phtml I've so far got:

```
<?php
$url = '';
$pageType = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $storeId = $store->getStoreId();
            switch ($pageType) {
                case 'product':
                $product  = Mage::registry('current_product');
                    $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product->getId())->getProductUrl();
                break;
                case 'category':
                $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            /* Below is the code that isn't working properly */
                    $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($category->getId())->getUrl();
                    break;
        default:
            $url = 'def';
                    break;
            }
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $url . '" hreflang="' . $store->getConfig('general/locale/code') . '"/>' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update:  I enclosed the code in an emulated store environment, and got the exactly the same category URL for each different language version - even worse than the first attempt:

    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
    $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($category->getId())->getUrl();
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

Comment: The odd thing with the original code is that it gives the category name in the correct language in each URL, but the store code stays the same - the current store being viewed.

If I change store language the store code in the output URLs changes to that store code.

I can't see why it would output the correct store code in the URL for each language in the product code, but it won't work for the category code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quickest solution I found:

```
$url = $store->getCurrentUrl(false) . Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($category->getId())->getUrlKey() . '.html';
```